# HTML Drop down section will not shift to href section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set a dropdown that can move to sections specified in herf

Here is my initial code

here are more details as to what I am trying to do as requested
I have a button panel and this drop-down
I am trying to switch between 2 when under specific px

```
<header>
    <div id="logo1"></div>
    <div id="logo2"></div>
    <div class="buttonpane">
        <button id="panel-links" onclick="location.href='#about-me-section'">ABOUT ME</button>
        <button id="panel-links" onclick="location.href='#projects-section'">PROJECTS</button>
        <button id="resume"><a onclick="location.href='documents/resume/resume.pdf';" download="Parth_Datwani_Resume" target="_blank">Resume</a></button>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropdown-btn" aria-haspopup="menu">
            <span>Menu</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-content" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#about-me-section">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#projects-section">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="href='documents/resume/resume.pdf">Resume</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

According to this, about should go to the about section and projects to projects as mentioned in herf tags
but the li a are not getting clicks or cannot process them.

I have tried this js below that I took from another stack post - I did change the `herf` to `data-herf` when I was attempting this - Yet I could not resolve this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[data-href]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var sectionToNavigate = $(this).attr('data-href');
        if(sectionToNavigate && $(sectionToNavigate).length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(sectionToNavigate).offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

My CSS I missed in original post

```
.dropdown-content li a {
    color: #000000; /* Adjust as needed */
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    pointer-events: all;
}


.dropdown-btn:focus + .dropdown-content,
.dropdown-btn:active + .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
/*------------------------------------------*/
#resume,#projects-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #ffff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#resume:hover,#projects-button:hover{
    background-color: #e5e1e2;
}
#resume a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: inherit;
  }

#panel-links{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background-color: #ffff;
    color: #000000;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

#panel-links:hover {
    background-color: #e5e1e2;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#projects-button{
    min-width: 40%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
    max-width: 13em;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
  
.dropdown-btn {
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffff;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #ffff;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0; /* Hide dropdown content by default */
    position: absolute; /* Position it relative to its parent */
    left: 50%; /* Start from the middle of the parent */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* Center it exactly */
    background-color: #ffffff; /* White background */
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); /* Optional: Adds a slight shadow for depth */
    z-index: 1; /* Ensure it's above other content */
}
.dropdown-content li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
}

.dropdown-content li a {
    color: #000000; /* Black text */
    display: block; /* Make each link fill its container for easier clicking */
}

.dropdown-btn:focus + .dropdown-content li {
    left: 0;
}
  
.dropdown-btn:focus + .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown-content li a:hover {
    background: #cbc9ca; /* Apply hover effect to the link's background */
}

.dropdown-content li:hover {
  background: #b7b1b4;
}
```

I have read other posts which conclude it is a browser issue. But I have tried Edge, chrome, and Brave, and none seem to work.

Comment: Please show a more complete example - ie include relevant HTML and if possible make a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What third-party libraries are you using? You clearly have jquery, but do you also have bootstrap (which version) etc?  It's possible one of these is being used to display your `dropdown-content` and also intercepting clicks on `<li><a>`

Comment: Your HTML, as provided *with extrapolated sections*, works fine.  https://jsfiddle.net/r6sft3wg/  Please [edit] your question so we can see it *not* working (ie so we can see the issue).  Perhaps your *other* (unprovided) HTML doesn't match?   See [mcve].

Comment: Are you getting any errors on your browser's devtools console? (have you remembered to load jquery for example?).

Comment: Sorry, I still think there is some missing HTML. Where are the elements with id about-me-section etc? It really would help us if you could create a runnable snippet.

Comment: I understood What would be the best way to resolev this should I seperate css ?? and thank you @AHaworth - The runnable showed me it was css

Comment: All those buttons in your `.buttonpane` element _should_ be just normal links instead. Don't _misuse_ HTML elements, just because you want a certain _look_. If you want links to _look like_ buttons - then apply according formatting. And _nesting_ `a` into `button`, as you did with the third one there, is not allowed in HTML to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
.dropdown-btn:focus + .dropdown-content { 
    display:block 
}
```

When you "click" on the displayed "about me", the `.dropdown-btn` loses focus first and thus the drop down disappears before the click event can fire. The click event then goes to the element that is now shown that was under the menu.

You can confirm this by holding the mouse button down instead of a down-up "click" action. The menu disappears as soon as you mouse down (and a click event is just mouse-down-up within a time limit)

The fix is to add a small `transition` to the menu so that it doesn't completely disappear between the button `blur` (lose of focus) and the `click` event.  You can tweak the transition times, eg increase for a more obvious fade-in/-out effect.

```
.dropdown-btn + .dropdown-content {
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;  
    transition:visibility 0.1s, opacity 0.1s linear;
}

.dropdown-btn:focus + .dropdown-content,
.dropdown-btn:active + .dropdown-content {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
```

(replacing the `display:block` and `display:none`)

Updated snippet (with some spacers to show it relocating to the anchor)

```css
.dropdown-content li a {
    color: #000000; /* Adjust as needed */
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.dropdown-btn + .dropdown-content {
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;  
    transition:visibility 0.1s, opacity 0.1s linear;
}

.dropdown-btn:focus + .dropdown-content,
.dropdown-btn:active + .dropdown-content {
    /*display: block;*/
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
    
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown {
    max-width: 13em;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
  
.dropdown-btn {
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffff;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #ffff;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    cursor: pointer;
}
  
.dropdown-content {
    /*display: none;*/
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0; /* Hide dropdown content by default */
    position: absolute; /* Position it relative to its parent */
    left: 50%; /* Start from the middle of the parent */
    transform: translateX(-50%); /* Center it exactly */
    background-color: #ffffff; /* White background */
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); /* Optional: Adds a slight shadow for depth */
    z-index: 1; /* Ensure it's above other content */
}
.dropdown-content li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 2px;
}

.dropdown-content li a {
    color: #000000; /* Black text */
    display: block; /* Make each link fill its container for easier clicking */
}

.dropdown-btn:focus + .dropdown-content li {
    left: 0;
}
  
.dropdown-btn:focus + .dropdown-content {
  visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown-content li a:hover {
    background: #cbc9ca; /* Apply hover effect to the link's background */
}

.dropdown-content li:hover {
  background: #b7b1b4;
}
```

```html
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropdown-btn" aria-haspopup="menu">
        <span>Menu</span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-content" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#about-me-section">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#projects-section">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div style='border:1px solid red; height:1500px;'>
    </div>

    <div id='about-me-section'>
      about me
    </div>

    <div style='border:1px solid green; height:500px;'>
    </div>

    <div id='projects-section'>
      projects
    </div>

    <div style='border:1px solid blue; height:500px;'>
    </div>
```